# Using Grizzly with JMS/ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration, grizzly

I'm working on proof-of-concept project designed to explore the benefits of offloading work from a NIO server to a message queue for backend processing. I'm using Grizzly for the NIO boilerplate stuff, and Spring Integration for the messaging (with JMS/ActiveMQ as the messaging implementation). Basically, what I want to do is this:

Client connection -> Server -> Server creates "work-to-be-done" message -> JMS/ActiveMQ

On the ActiveMQ message queue, a number of "workers" will be actively consuming these messages, processing them, and placing the result on another queue. The server is listening for "response messages" on that queue, and once a message is picked up it will execute the following:

Response queue -> Server serializes the message to something the client can understand -> back to the client

My immediate problem is my lack of understanding of Grizzly, specifically how to decouple the event handling from the messaging. The server has to create the work-to-be-done message in such a way that when the reply message comes back from the worker, the server knows who the client was (find the related FilterChainContext in Grizzly) in order to send the tcp message.

I might be able to use FilterChainContext.getAddress() and place that on the work message, but I'm not sure how to code a method which takes a peer address and a message and somehow sends that (FilterChainContext.write()) when it has no FilterChainContext.

I'm playing with the idea now of keeping a Map around, but I'm apprehensive about this approach because I don't want stuff to go stale in a map if something happens to the message during serialization or processing.

Ideas and suggestions are welcome.

-Michael

Comment: Have you tried keeping a reference to the FilterChainContext in your work-to-be-done message and pass said reference to your reply so that your filter can obtain it and write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the TCP adapters/gateways (which have an option to use NIO), together with custom (de)serializers. If you must use Grizzly, you could write a server connection factory implementation. In the case of the outbound adapter (or inbound gateway), the endpoint is registered as a 'TcpListener' (using the connectionId) and the SI message contains the `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header used to determine which connection gets the reply. When a connection closes, it is unregistered (removed from the map).